# v107 Getting Status Code of MethodNotAllowed on a Post Request that Used to Work

Tags: restsharp

I am trying to get an auth token using RestSharp v107 and I cannot figure out how to make it work. I have included the previous method that worked fine until updating to v107. Any ideas?

v107 Code that returns StatusCode = MethodNotAllowed:

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetAuthTokenAsync()
    {
        GetCreds();
        var client = new RestClient(_authUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_authClientId, _authClientSecret);

        var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
        var deserializedResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content);
        string authToken = deserializedResponse["access_token"];
        return authToken;
    }
```

Old Code that worked fine before v107:

```
private static string GetAuthToken()
    {
        GetCreds();
        var client = new RestClient(_authUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.POST };

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_authClientId, _authClientSecret);

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
        var deserializedResponse = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
        string authToken = deserializedResponse["access_token"];
        return authToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See what happens if you define the method at instantiation:

```
var request = new RestRequest(_authUrl, Method.Post)
    .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
```

(also you can add parameters in the same statement)

Let me know if it has been resolved, because i'm struggling with v107 too :D

Comment: Adding the content type header in this case isn't necessary, RestSharp will add it. POST requests use `FormUrlEncodedContent` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening an issue in the RestSharp repository, so I can help you.

There are a couple of changes in your code that I would recommend.

- Do not instantiate RestSharp for each call. You have a private property `_authUrl`, so instead you should instantiate `RestClient` in the constructor and keep it in a private field like `_client`
- Don't add content type headers manually. RestSharp adds all the necessary content headers based on the request type and parameters.

You can trace the request using, for example, `HttpTracer`, as [described](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#delegating-handlers) in the docs. You can then easily see if the request is somehow broken.

The code could look like this:

```
private async Task<string> GetAuthTokenAsync()
{
    GetCreds();
    var request = new RestRequest().AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    var response = await client.PostAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>(request);
    return response["access_token"];
}
```

**UPDATE** The issue was caused by some wrong values in the `Accept` header set by RestSharp, which has been fixed.

Comment: I have done what was suggested and still have the issue. I made a report in the RestSharp repo. See https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107

Comment: sorry, the correct link to my report is: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1707

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I included an extra header as per documentation examples that must have been causing a redirect in laravel from a Get to a Post.

```
//client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //bad in my case
client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "application/json"); //good in my case
```